# Using temp table in PL/pgSQL procedure for cleaning tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, select-into

I'm trying to delete all data related to a user id from a game database.

There is a table holding all games (each played by 3 players):

```
# select * from pref_games where gid=321;
 gid | rounds |          finished
-----+--------+----------------------------
 321 |     17 | 2011-10-26 17:16:04.074402
(1 row)
```

And there is a table holding players scores for that game #321:

```
# select * from pref_scores where gid=321;
      id       | gid | money | quit
----------------+-----+-------+------
 OK531282114947 | 321 |   218 | f
 OK501857527071 | 321 |  -156 | f
 OK429671947957 | 321 |   -62 | f
```

When I try the following SELECT INTO statement on the psql-prompt of PostgreSQL it seems to work as expected (and the temp table disappears when session is closed):

```
# select gid into temp temp_gids from pref_scores where id='OK446163742289';
SELECT

# select * from temp_gids ;
 gid
------
 1895
 1946
 1998
 2094
 2177
 2215
(6 rows)
```

But when I try to create my PL/pgSQL procedure I get error:

```
    create or replace function pref_delete_user(_id varchar)
        returns void as $BODY$
            begin

            select gid into temp temp_gids from pref_scores where id=_id;
            delete from pref_scores where gid in
                (select gid from temp_gids);
            delete from pref_games where gid in
                (select gid from temp_gids);

            delete from pref_rep where author=_id;
            delete from pref_rep where id=_id;

            delete from pref_catch where id=_id;
            delete from pref_game where id=_id;
            delete from pref_hand where id=_id;
            delete from pref_luck where id=_id;
            delete from pref_match where id=_id;
            delete from pref_misere where id=_id;
            delete from pref_money where id=_id;
            delete from pref_pass where id=_id;
            delete from pref_status where id=_id;
            delete from pref_users where id=_id;

            end;
    $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

The error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at "temp"
DETAIL:  Expected record variable, row variable, or list of scalar variables following INTO.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "pref_delete_user" near line 3
```

Why is that (temp tables not allowed here?) and where to save my temp list of the gid's to be deleted?

(And I'd prefer not to use "on delete cascade" because I'm not used to it yet and my scripts/database isn't prepared for that yet).

Comment: `SELECT INTO` has different meaning in plpgsql.

Comment: Yes thanks, so what to use here instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create the temporary table and then do the usual `INSERT ... SELECT` as separate operations:

```
create temporary table temp_gids (gid int not null) on commit drop;
insert into temp_gids (gid) select gid from pref_scores where id = _id;
```

There's also a [LIKE option to CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) if you want to duplicate a table's structure:

> `LIKE parent_table [ like_option ... ]`
>   The `LIKE` clause specifies a table from which the new table automatically copies all column names, their data types, and their not-null constraints.

But I think you just need a temporary table to hold some IDs so that's probably overkill.

`SELECT INTO` works as you expect [*outside* a procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html):

> [...] this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently.

`SELECT INTO` is used to store the result of a SELECT in a local variable [inside a PostgreSQL procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

> The result of a SQL command yielding a single row (possibly of multiple columns) can be assigned to a record variable, row-type variable, or list of scalar variables. This is done by writing the base SQL command and adding an `INTO` clause.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need ON COMMIT DROP when creating temp table here inside my procedure?

Comment: @Alexander: Couldn't hurt but you'd want to wrap the procedure's guts in a transaction (which you probably want to do anyway if you're doing a bunch of cleanup and don't want to leave the job half done).

Comment: @muistooshort what do you mean by "wrap the procedure's guts in a transaction"?

Comment: @Erwin: Is a single procedure call a transaction? If not he could have a half finished clean up if one of the DELETEs failed.

Comment: @muistooshort: The body of a function is **always** executed as a transaction: it all succeeds or it all fails. No need for an explicit transaction.

Comment: @muistooshort: You can use dblink if you need changes to be permanent and not rolled back on an error. (That's **not** what you usually want - and not what you were talking about here. Just for the sake of completeness). See this entry in the [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_don.27t_BEGIN.2C_ROLLBACK_and_COMMIT_work_in_stored_procedures.2Ffunctions.3F).

Comment: @Erwin: Thanks, I've never needed to care for any of the procedures I've written so I've never needed to look it up. So ON COMMIT DROP is probably a good idea?

Comment: @Alexander: You might be interested in the back-and-forth I've just had with Erwin about transactions. I'd now say "yes, you probably do want ON COMMIT DROP on the temporary table".

Answer (score 19):

#### Data modifying CTE

Since Postgres **9.1** use [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) for simple cases like the one at hand:

```sql
WITH gids AS (
   SELECT gid FROM pref_scores
   WHERE  id = _id
   )
, d1 AS (  
   DELETE FROM pref_scores p
   USING  gids t
   WHERE  p.gid = t.gid
   )
   -- more work using gids?
DELETE FROM pref_games p
USING  gids t
WHERE  p.gid = t.gid;
```

#### Temp table

In most cases, you don't need an *actual* temporary table. Exceptions would be when an index on the temp table helps performance, or when you need the same temp table for more purposes.

There is a simpler way to do it: **`CREATE TEMP TABLE AS`**
As [recommended in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html):

> This command is functionally similar to `SELECT INTO`, but it is
> preferred since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of
> the `SELECT INTO` syntax. Furthermore, `CREATE TABLE AS` offers a superset
> of the functionality offered by `SELECT INTO`.

It would also be more efficient to use **[`DELETE .. USING ..`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html)** instead of a sub-select.
And yes, unless you plan to use the temp table in the same session after the transaction committed, add `ON COMMIT DROP`.

Putting it all together, your function could look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pref_delete_user(_id varchar)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN    
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_gids ON COMMIT DROP AS
   SELECT gid FROM pref_scores WHERE id = _id;

   DELETE FROM pref_scores p
   USING  tmp_gids t
   WHERE  p.gid = t.gid;

   DELETE FROM pref_games p
   USING  tmp_gids t
   WHERE  p.gid = t.gid;

   -- more deletes ...    
END
$func$;
```

Note: this can't be a plain SQL function, because that cannot reference objects that are only created in the same function.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I saw remarkable performance benefits on postgres 8.3 using an array of ids instead of a temp table. Something like `deleter_ids = array(select id from ... where ...); delete from tbl where gid = ANY(deleter_ids);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
EXECUTE 'create temp table temp_gids AS select from pref_scores where id=$1'
    USING _id;
```